# JAXB - unmarshalling from url

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm tryting to display title and id of game from this site:
http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=2

When I was unmarshalling from this url: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml it was all ok, but here was just one object, not a list. So I'm having problem now. I was reading some tutorials and examples from Google and I made this code:

Data.java:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "Data" )
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
    @XmlElement(name = "Game")
    List<Game> games;

    public List<Game> getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(List<Game> games) {
        this.games = games;
    }
}
```

Game.java file:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Game")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Game {
    private int id;
    private String gameTitle;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGameTitle(){
        return gameTitle;
    }

    public void setGameTitle(String gameTitle){
        this.gameTitle = gameTitle;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale) throws MalformedURLException {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    JAXBExample test = new JAXBExample();
    Game customer = test.readXML();
    model.addObject("customer", customer);
    return model;
}
```

JAXBExample.java:

```
public class JAXBExample {
    public Game readXML() throws MalformedURLException {
        Data customer = null;
        Game game = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class);
            URL url = new URL("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=2");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            customer = (Data) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(url);
            List<Game> games = customer.getGames();
            game = games.get(0);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return game;
    }
}
```

And index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
        Name: ${customer.gameTitle}<br />
        Id: ${customer.id}<br />
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

But my code isn't working. Somebody have maybe idea what I'm doing wrong? Because as result I just get:

```
Name:
Id:
```

And nothing more.

Comment: What tutorials did you follow? I need to do the same but with spring boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that is wrong with your annotation is

```
public class Game {
  private int id;
  @XmlElement(name = "GameTitle") //You need to add this since first letter is uppercase, otherwise the GameTitle will not unmarshall.
  private String gameTitle; 
  ... your code ...
}
```

**So why is it not the rest working?**

> Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=2

[403 = Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

**Solution** (make the server believe you are a browser)

```
URL url = new URL("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=2");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
http.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
customer = (Data) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
List<Game> games = customer.getGames();
game = games.get(0);
```

Note: `Try catch final`, close streams and checking for `NullPointer` is beyond this example and up to user.

Comment: Why are you using "game = games.get(0);"? I followed your steps but my 2nd sub child element is blank/null.

Comment: game = games.get(0); is from OP code, it's to retrive the first <Game> node

Comment: When I try to print an list from "JAXBExample.java:" I get [first_value, blank] If I copied the exact code to my main class. I get [first_value, Second_value]

Comment: @Mike.Chun I don't really understand what you are up to, op's code is to retrive first Game node.. so first element in the list, I guess the length of the list depends on id of game...

Comment: @Mike.Chun I found your question in the deleted answer on this questions, from what I have seen serge answer is correct.

Comment: I followed his methodology it works, but when I print the list to string. I only get the first value. The second value is blank. I've updated the post once again.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Would you happen to know how would this look with Spring boot?