# Specifying root and child nodes with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, well-formed

Staying within `JAXB` how would I refactor `MyNote` so that it [conforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34278493/262852) to:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Which [is](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) well formed but not valid, to my understanding.  Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyNotes>
    <Note>
        <note>XY3Z1RGEO9W79LALCS</note>
        <to>LJAY9RNMUGGENGNND9</to>
        <from>GOVSHVZ3GJWC864L7X</from>
        <heading>EX6LGVE5LGY4A6B9SK</heading>
        <body>L95WYQNMEU1MFDRBG4</body>
    </Note>
</MyNotes>
```

which is too flat, rather than nested as the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml).

I believe this makes `note` the `root` element, with other elements being `children` nodes to `note` if I'm using correct terminology.

The `MyNote` class:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.jaxb.hello.world;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder = {"note", "to", "from", "heading", "body"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "note")
public class MyNote {

    private String note;
    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String heading;
    private String body;

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "note")
    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "to")
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "from")
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "heading")
    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "body")
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return note + to + from + heading + body;
    }

}
```

The `MyNotes` class:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.jaxb.hello.world;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "MyNotes")
public class MyNotes {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyNotes.class.getName());

    private List<MyNote> myNotes = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyNotes() {
    }

    public List<MyNote> getMyNotes() {
        LOG.info(myNotes.toString());
        return myNotes;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Note")
    public void setMyNotes(List<MyNote> myNotes) {
        LOG.info(myNotes.toString());
        this.myNotes = myNotes;
    }

    public void add(MyNote myNote) {
        LOG.info(myNote.toString());
        myNotes.add(myNote);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        for (MyNote note : this.myNotes) {
            str.append(note.toString());
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

}
```

[exercising](https://github.com/THUFIR/com.danibuiza.jaxb.ultimate) the `MyNote` and `MyNotes` classes:

```
    public MyNotes unmarshallMyNotesFromFile(URI uri) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(uri);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyNotes.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        MyNotes myNotes = (MyNotes) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        return myNotes;
    }

    public void marshallMyNotesAndWriteToFile(MyNotes notes, URI uri) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyNotes.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(notes, new File(uri));
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(notes, System.out);
    }
```

I'm looking to [grab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34278493/262852) this `xml` through the web; first need to [match](https://github.com/THUFIR/com.danibuiza.jaxb.ultimate) the structure to the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. You need to change how you name your xmlElement for myNotes in MyNotes class. Also MyNote should not have a note field itself (according to your desired xml). Your edited classes would look like this (I also removed the logging statements for my convenience):

```
@XmlType(propOrder = { "to", "from", "heading", "body"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "note")
public class MyNote {

    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String heading;
    private String body;

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "to")
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "from")
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "heading")
    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "body")
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  to + from + heading + body;
    }

}
```

and MyNotes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyNotes")
public class MyNotes {

    private List<MyNote> myNotes = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyNotes() {
    }

    public List<MyNote> getMyNotes() {
        return myNotes;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "note")
    public void setMyNotes(List<MyNote> myNotes) {
        this.myNotes = myNotes;
    }

    public void add(MyNote myNote) {
        myNotes.add(myNote);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        for (MyNote note : this.myNotes) {
            str.append(note.toString());
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that indents `to`, `from`, `heading` and `body` as child nodes to `note`?

Comment: @Thufir, yes I tried it. Did you experience something different?

Comment: **yes, your solution works, answer accepted of course.**  no gettter/setter on `note` attribute for `MyNote` as `note` is the root attribute?

Comment: @Thufir I removed the note field from MyNote class entirely, as you desired xml within the note element has only to, from, heading and body. Else you would have note within the note.

Comment: how does this relate to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html ?

Comment: You can use XmlElementWrapper to add an extra layer in your xml. As mentioned in the documentation usually it is used to wrap around collections. For example if you wanted (for some reason) <MyNotes><TechNotes><note>...</note></TechNotes></MyNotes>, you could add @XmlElementWrapper(name="TechNotes") above setMyNotes method.  It wraps around an XmlElement, so you cannot use it to wrap note around to, from, heading, body at the same time. They need a common parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186378/discussion-between-thufir-and-mart).